# How to make JavaScript variables available to ES6 modules

Tags: javascript

Say I have a website with a file structure like this:

```
index.html
main.js
modules/my-module.js
```

index.html contains (along with a lot of HTML):

```
<button id='my-btn'>My Button</button>
<script type='module' src='./main.js'></script>
```

main.js contains:

```
import { myBtn } from "./modules/my-module.js";
```

and modules/my-module.js contains:

```
const myBtn = document.querySelector("#my-btn");
myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Hallo from My Button");
});
export { myBtn };
```

Now if I click on the button I get an alert as expected.

The problem I am having is that I have some information (ie variables with values such as strings, arrays etc) in other script tags on the index.html page which I need in modules/my-module.js

I do not want to use a global variable for this because they are evil.

I thought of creating an element(s) on the index.html page with data set attributes as keys and assign values to them. The element could then be accessed from modules/my-module.js and its data set attributes would be readable. This does work when I try it but it seems a long winded way of getting access to information available on the index.html page.

It has been suggested I create a class or function returned by the module and pass data into it. The problem with that, to me, is that I am trying to keep code related to the same thing all together in the same module. If I have to pass functions out of the module to be invoked with extra data then my code base is less well organised.

Is there any other approach which would be more direct?

Comment: A module should not refer to specific hardcoded ids. It should provide its generic functionality in the form of functions where any specific data is passed as parameters. This also answers your question: don't do any of this, rather call the module function while passing data defined in the index file.

Comment: The point of a module is to be reusable. If the module is highly specific to a single project, why create a module in the first place? "less well organized" is using a pointless module that could just be a script and access the data directly.

Comment: Perhaps I am using modules to provide something they are not designed to do. When you say 'a script' do you mean, for example, a javascript file referenced by a script tag in index.html without the type='module' attribute?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use modules like you do, but again, it seems pointless if the module isn't reusable in a different project.